# Android - Error: Cannot Find Symbol public Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar p0) throws java.lang.Throwable

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I just added Xamarin.Android.Support packages to my solution, tried to compile and received the below errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    public Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar p0) throws java.lang.Throwable

error: package android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat does not exist
        android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat.OnInflateListener
```

Here are the packages installed:

1. Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (23.4.0.1)
2. Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable (23.4.0.1)
3. Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (23.4.0.1)
4. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (23.4.0.1)
5. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView (23.4.0.1)
6. Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable (23.4.0.1)

I tried installing Android Support Library through the main Android SDK Manager, but that made no difference.

Where can I obtain these missing packages?

Comment: This should be apart of the `Support.v7.AppCompat` package. Secondly, I cannot get this to replicate on my machine given the packages you listed. Do you have a sample application you can upload and provide the link? That should help investigating this issue.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/trycatchdonothing/TestAndroid Barebones Android project with only AppCompat package and its dependencies added. I get 59 build errors on this project, all related to the Support library.

Comment: This repo compiles just fine on my end. Are these errors closely related to these? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Also please add all the errors via the build output logs.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Something was wrong with the zip file in Xamarin/zips, so I downloaded from the link you sent, renamed as the corresponding MD5 hash, cleaned, rebuilt and was able to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `Support.*` Cache is not corrupted or partially downloaded. Please see this document I wrote for more information:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/